# How to download a file by using split size -Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.5

I am downloading a video file from a server using a PHP link.

```
url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com:80/server/filedownload.php?action=download&filename=file.3gp&&split=0.56907272338867"];
```

so this the split i am using. The file is getting downloaded, but the size of the file is only 4kB. how to download the complete file and after the download is completed how to combine the splits to make a complete video file.

Comment: As per my knowledge you can do something like on completion of first split download, download the next split download as you download the first split. The delegate method `connectionDidFinishLoading:connection` will be helpful to you to know that the first split download is done completely.

Comment: I assume that you have used the NSURLConnection object to download the data :)

Comment: @Wolvorin i am using NSURLConnection. Thanks i'l try!